# How can I get the keys of a node.js hash from a C++ module?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I have a C++ module that's being called from node.js. I would like to pass in a hash and retrieve both the keys and values from the C++ code but I cannot figure out how to get them. Here's what I would like to handle:

```
var mod = require('MyModule')
var conn = mod.createConnection()
conn.connect( { 'uid': 'graeme',
                'pwd': 'mypassword' } )
```

Inside my C++ method, I can use `args[0]->IsObject()` to determine that the parameter is a hash, but I can't find a way to get the keys ('uid', 'pwd') or the values ('graeme', 'mypassword') from it.

Is there a way to get the keys and values from these kinds of objects?

Comment: Why would you set the parameters on an array like that? Then you are just adding arbitrary attributes onto an empty array. `cs['uid'] = 'graeme'` doesn't add to the array, it assigns  an attribute tangentially to the values in the array.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Ah, thanks for that. I am fairly new to Javascript and found code similar to that somewhere online. I was under the impression that the second code was essentially creating the same sort of object as the first.

Comment: No prob. They both create objects with the same keys, it is just that the second one is also an Array (a subclass of `Object`). Having it be an array is confusing though, since it has no integer keys and is thus an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example of passing in an array doesn't really make sense, but to your general point, you can use `GetOwnPropertyNames` to read the names of properties.

```
Local<Object> obj = args[0].As<Object>();
Local<Array> props = obj->GetOwnPropertyNames();

for (int i = 0, len = props->Length(); i < len; i++){
    Local<String> key = props->Get(i).As<String>();
    Local<Value> val = obj->Get(key);
}
```

equivalent to:

```
var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arguments[0]);
for (var i = 0, len = props.length; i < len; i++){
    var key = props[i];
    var value = arguments[0][key];
}
```

Comment: Oops, that is what I get from going from memory. I've updated my answer and actually tested it now.